# Sunday is my {cheat day}

Tags: phrase-request, usage

I came across the following sentence:

> Sunday is my cheat day, so I'm gonna really pig out.

I am wondering, can "cheat day" be used when talking about a day when I do not stick to a certain commitment that I made other than a diet, such as working on a project or building a new habit? And if not, is there an equivalent phrase that can be used in these cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not limit 'cheat day' to just diet but would also allow it for an exercise plan. I would not likely use it outside these two areas.

One phrase I might use for other sorts of commitments is "let slide".